# Why we use service classes in spring hibernate integration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I want to know the use of service classes in J2EE.

I have 2 projects.

One is in spring hibernate integration.That project contain DAO,MODEL,SERVICE and CONTROLLER.Within that The request is access by the controller and send to the values to the dao class through the service class.

2nd project contain only BEAN,CONTROLLER and DERIVED classes.Within that the request is access by the controller and send the values directly to the derived class.Query is written in this derived class.

I want to know the difference between these two projects. Why we use service class ?

Comment: These are architectural differences and could be chosen based on your requirements. For example, learn more about MVC if you would like to know more about modal view controller architecture. However, simply, these 'layered architectures' were built based on their responsibilities. DAO's, Modal's, Service's and Controller's all have different responsibilities.

Comment: Edit improves reading capability of question. Now question will be easily read out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in my experience, service class contains all business , calculate, logic
for example in login module :
base on MVC pattern
Model class (DAO,MODEL is call model) : User, UserDAO
Controller : UserController
View : LoginPage
That's doesn't mean we cannot create another class like Service
we can have UserBusinessthis class contain all method, logic realted to User like validateUserLogin ... etc
application may work like : 
User access LoginPageinput value and submit => UserController=> UserBusiness=> UserDAO
we need divide to easy handle and maintain
In spring we have some annotation like

```
@Business
@Repository
@Controller
```

that is a maker spring will create a object , we no need to using "new" keyword.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply.:)

Answer (score 2):

Controllers: are used to just delegating the calls, meaning once the request arrive on controller it will forward it to relative service

Services: Service are develop to write the business logic in general.

Dao: Data transfer object, which intend to deal with the DTO's

So, Briefly, when Spring MVC receive a call. I will lend to controller, controller than redirects it to respective service. Service performs business login if any on the api call and than delegated data updation to DAO layer.

Comment: Is there any advantage with the use of service class?

Comment: The advantage here is for clear separation between all layers. If there is no service layer than you have to write down the business logic either on controller layer or on DAO layer. which is not right  way to doing this.

we should have clear separation between roles and responsibilities of different layers.

Comment: @GayathriRajan, purpose of service is to write your business logic, that is what Jaydatt is saying. Just for example, you have a calculator application, then controller will just pick the values from user where as the service will perform the actual logic for example addition, subtraction etc

Comment: Thank You very much for the help.:)